# Right usage of JbpmContext with transactions

Tags: jbpm

Can anybody explain the right usage of JbpmContext?
When transaction is opening? When we create new JbpmContext or when we call close()? If I saving processInstance, will be it saved if I don't call close() method?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are working on the jbpm 3 or 4 version. I have worked on version 3.2.7 where if we are saving the process instance then it will be saved even if we don't close the jbpmContext.

Regarding the jbpmContext it act similar to the application context in the j2ee application just here it is acting for jbpm application. It is useful for creating processInstances/ taskinstances deploying process etc..